# Select Multiple Collection View Cells and Store in Array

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I'm working on an onboarding flow for my iOS App in Swift. I'd like to allow users to tap other users in a collection view and have it follow those users. I need the collection view to be able to allow multiple cells to be selected, store the cells in an array and run a function once the users taps the next button. Here's my controller code:

```
class FollowUsers: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var tableData: [SwiftyJSON.JSON] = []

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var loadingView: UIView!

private var selectedUsers: [SwiftyJSON.JSON] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.getCommunities()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func getUsers() {


        Alamofire.request(.GET, "url", parameters: parameters)
            .responseJSON {response in
                if let json = response.result.value {
                    let jsonObj = SwiftyJSON.JSON(json)

                    if let data = jsonObj.arrayValue as [SwiftyJSON.JSON]? {
                        self.tableData = data
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        self.loadingView.hidden = true
                    }
                }
        }

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableData.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: UserViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("userCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserViewCell

    let rowData = tableData[indexPath.row]

    if let userName = rowData["name"].string {
        cell.userName.text = userName
    }

    if let userAvatar = rowData["background"].string {
        let url = NSURL(string: userAvatar)
        cell.userAvatar.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.userAvatar.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        cell.userAvatar.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell: UserViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("userCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserViewCell

    let rowData = tableData[indexPath.row]
    let userName = rowData["name"].string
    let userId = rowData["id"].int


    selectedUsers.append(rowData[indexPath.row])

    print("Cell \(userId) \(userName) selected")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collection.dataSource = self
        collection.delegate = self
        collection.allowsMultipleSelection = true

        self.getCommunities()
    }
```

You should be able to make multiple selections with this.